# Couldn't Light have relinquished ownership of the Death Note before dying?

Tags: death-note

Before Ryuk killed Light, was it possible that Light could have relinquished ownership of the Death Note so Ryuk wouldn't write his name?

Comment: Ryuk said that he will be the one to write Light's name, when he will die. It has nothing to do with the ownership of the notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Light actually relinquished ownership of the one Death Note he had back in Episode 29.** Right before that point, Misa was the owner of Gelus' Death Note, Light was the owner of Rem's and Mello's mafia underling was the owner of Sidoh's. After giving up ownership, Light has Misa lend him her DN so that he doesn't lose his memories. She is still the owner since she still has her Shinigami eyes. **Light never takes back ownership of any DN for the rest of the anime.** I guess we can assume he keeps some sliver of a DN page on his body somewhere to make sure he has all the memories.

The fact that Light is not currently an owner of a DN is not relevant. At the very end of the last episode of the anime, no human is actually in ownership of any of the Death Notes. However, **Ryuk still has to write the names of the original owner in his DN.** according to Rule LXIV:

> If nobody claims the ownership of the Death Note [...] gods of death
>   are [still] obliged to confirm the death of the first owner and write
>   down that humans name in his/her Death Note even when he/she is in the
>   world of gods of death.

(http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note)

Comment: You right about the thing Light didn't claim ownership, but he still counts as the owner, as Mikami couldn't see Light's life-span, meaning Light is the owner of the Death Note. but you are right about it doesn't matter if Light will relinquish ownership of the Death Note, he still will be killed by Ryuk.

Answer (score 0):

in the box thing below there are massive spoilers for death note only hover over it if you have watched the anime

> It would not matter as he only had a small snippet of the book (corner i belive) and the police have the book as they caught the person that had the real book and swapped it with a fake book as it broke his schedual and as @trim24 has stated Ryuk stated when light died (or when he time was up) he would write his name in the book, I think you forget that there are 2 books one is given to Ryuk (wont go in to much detail) the police only have 1 book

Comment: Does it actually matter how much of the book Light had? It was established earlier in the series that "owning" a Death Note is sort of a mystical connection with its own rules that doesn't seem to be strictly related to actually having the book on your person. I interpreted the question as asking whether Ryuk writing Light's name in the book was connected to his mystical "ownership" of the book and if giving that up (and I guess also his memories of the book, going by earlier episodes) would have saved Light.